# How to search for videos using GettyImages Connect API

Tags: api

I'm trying to use this API to search for videos. I have a client key, secret, and everything I need.
I have scoured the API doc page up and down several times, and can't find any reference to video search.
The on-site search allows video search, and the API works fine when I search videos.

I use:
`'https://connect.gettyimages.com/v3/search/images/editorial?phrase=' + query + '&fields=id%2Ctitle%2Ccaption%2Cpreview` to search for images, and I've tried every combination of the word 'video' in that to search for videos, to no avail.

The images search works great, by the way.

The "swagger" interactive page (most annoying way to display an API doc, by the way) has a section for images, search/images, etc, but no video search or video (using video id).

the v3 API release notes states that they now have support for video search and download. Where?

Thanks to anyone that can lend a hand here, this is probably the most confusing API I've ever encountered.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

sorry it's taken so long answer your question! At the time you posted, I don't think we had our video-specific search and download endpoints up. They are there now, though they're still in beta. Should be that way for a couple more weeks.

https://connect.gettyimages.com/swagger/ui/index.html#!/Search

Searching for "video" via the image search endpoints will not give you video files.

Thanks,

Matt
Getty Images API operations